# Codeigniter Cache

Tags: codeigniter

I'm trying to implement caching in code igniter.  I'm completely new to this so it might be a dumb question but lets see if there's an answer out there.

I've gone to database.php and enabled caching and placed my path.  I believe the path is fine because my delete all files call removes the index.html and the htaccess file from that folder.  However nothing gets cached as I use the app.  I've tried to turn cache on using $this->db_cacheon() but nothing seems to write any files to that folder.  My setup is that I have models to handle the connection to the database table in question.  So inside of that model I would do a select from tablename and try to have that cached but nothing seems to happen.  Does anyone have an idea what I could do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

There are three types of caching. I don't know much about database caching. I have done output caching.

```
$this->output->cache(n);
```

Whatever page you want to cache,
you can use this in controller function which loads your view page.

You can find your cache pages in system/cache folder.

Comment: I'm trying to cache api calls from an app.  So would I be putting that above any of those calls to cache the response?  Do I then have to tell it to retrieve the cached answer?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean `$this->db->cache_on()`

Have a look at the manual:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/caching.html

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/caching.html

Comment: Sorry yes I absolutely did mean that I'll take a look at these now.

Comment: So I actually had read these before and did setup the first one for database caching.  This does seem to allow me to delete files from the cache folder so my path is correct.  The problem is that nothing is getting cached.  I'm wondering if something is going wrong with using activerecord and using the objects to handle db calls instead of this->db-> I honestly don't know